# Proof of the following complex inequalities

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers, proof-writing

How to prove the following complex inequalities:

$$|\sin(zx)|\leq e^{|Imz|x}$$
$$|e^{izy}\sin(z(x-y))|\leq e^{|Imz|x}, y\leq x$$
$$\left|\dfrac{\sin(zx)}{z}\right|\leq axe^{|Imz|x}$$

where $a$ is a constant, $z$ is complex number and $x$ is non-negative real number.

I think this can be proved by the Taylor series expansion but I could not figure out why this constant $a$ is appearing and how to separate the imaginary part of higher powers of $z$ in Taylor series.

Any alternative way will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

For the first one, let $z=u+iv$ where $u=\text{Re}(z)$ and $v=\text{Im}(z)$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
|\sin(xz)|&=\left|\sin(x(u+iv))\right|\\\\
&=\frac12|e^{-xv}e^{ixu}+e^{xv}e^{-ixu}|\\\\
&\le \frac12\left(e^{xv}+e^{-xv}\right)\\\\
&\le e^{|xv|}\\\\
&=e^{x|v|}\\\\
&=e^{x|\text{Im}(z)|}
\end{align}$$

You can handle the rest analogously by just using straightforward analysis.